# React material-ui, grid list cannot render grid items

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

```
export interface FlatsGridProps {
    flats: IClusterFlats[];
}

export const FlatsGrid: React.StatelessComponent<FlatsGridProps> = (props: FlatsGridProps) => {

        if (props.flats.length === 0) {
            return (<div> empty </div>);
        }

        return (
            <div style={styles.root}>
                <GridList
                    cols={2}
                    style={styles.gridList}
                    cellHeight={180}>
                    {props.flats.map((f, i) => {
                        <div key={i}> element </div>
                    })}
                </GridList>
            </div>
        )
    };
```

When I render GridList control it throws exception

> Cannot read property 'props' of null in GridList.js

View from console below.

[image: console log]

Comment: Looks like your error lies somewhere else than the code shown. Are you sure you are showing use the `GridList.js:86`??

Comment: GridList.js comes from material-ui library. https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/GridList/GridList.js 74 line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to `return` the child from the map. The `grid.js` complains about its `child` being `undefined`.

```
 <GridList
   cols={2}
   style={styles.gridList}
   cellHeight={180}>
   {props.flats.map((f, i) => {
     return (<div key={i}> element </div>)
   })}
 </GridList>
```